# Position on ::after in table-cell doesn't work in Firefox?

Tags: css

The following code should create a pseudo-element which spans 100% of its parent element's width. However this won't work in Firefox, it does work in Chrome. Firefox seems to ignore the `.parent`'s `position:relative`. Is this a bug?

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent{
  background:red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  display:table-cell;
}

.parent:after{
left:0;
  content:'';
  right:0;
  top:10px;
  height:20px;
  background:green;
  position:absolute;
}
```

[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/9eEVN6Pj)

See this images in **chrome** 
[image]

and now see this result in **firefox**

---

[image]

Comment: What's the desired effect? Is there content in the :after or is it just a bar?

Comment: Could you please add some context? It's very important how the surrounding elements are displayed and whether you use a wrapper. Otherwise this seems to be a bug in Firefox, even good old IE displays the `::after` element correctly.

Comment: Someone should file this as a bug to Mozilla, it's still relevant in Firefox 25.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=932784

Answer (score 1):

If possible, change the `display:table-cell` to `block` or `inline-block` to fix this error. Alternatively, change `position:relative` on the parent to `absolute`.

Comment: no it's not possible because i used to tow div side by side . I m using table-cell for equal height purpose so i can't remove table-cell properites in my div

Comment: @RohitAzad change position to absolute?

Comment: `position:absolute`? This will result in all blocks rendered at the `top:0;left:0;` position relative to the next parent with a non-static position value. It won't work.

Comment: @Zeta sure, but it fixes the problem. And I guess he has a wrapper-element around those divs, so absolute positioning would be no problem.

Comment: @Christoph: ["I used to tow div side by side"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736050/position-on-after-in-table-cell-doesnt-work-in-firefox/11736198#comment15575118_11736198) ~~> "I'm using the divs on the same level in the DOM and apply `display:table-cell` on them in order to achieve an equal height on each element". I suppose he doesn't have a wrapper around those.

Comment: well, at least the `<body>` will be a wrapper:-p And you can achieve equal height very nicely with absolute positioning if the content is not too random.

Answer (score 0):

Give `width`

```
  .parent:after{
      left:0;
      content:'';
      right:0;
      top:10px;
      width:100px;
      height:20px;
      background:green;
      position:absolute;
}
```