# Box-shadow for each table cell not showing in Firefox

Tags: css

I need to make box-shadow for each table cell using **:before** pseudo element. It works perfect in all browsers except firefox.

**CSS**

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.box2 .c-table {
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #e5e3d5;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e3d5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebe8da;
    border-right: 1px solid #ebe8da;
}

.box .c-table {
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #e0ded1;
    border-top: 1px solid #e0ded1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e4d6;
    border-right: 1px solid #e6e4d6;
}

.inbox .c-table {
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #e0ded1;
    border-top: 1px solid #e0ded1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e4d6;
    border-right: 1px solid #e6e4d6;
}

.c-table tr > td {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
}

.c-table tr + tr {
    border-top: 1px solid #f0eee0;
}

.c-table td + td {
    border-left: 1px solid #f0eee0;
}

.c-table td:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: '';
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}

.inbox {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #444444;
    padding: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #d3d2c5;
    border: 1px solid #f0eee0;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px rgba(240,238,224,1), 1px 1px rgba(240,238,224,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}

.box2 .inbox {
    border-left: 1px solid #e5e3d5;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e3d5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebe8da;
    border-right: 1px solid #ebe8da;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="inbox margin-space">
    <table class="c-table ">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="th">
                <td>column1</td>
                <td>column2</td>
                <td>column3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row1</td>
                <td>row2</td>
                <td>row3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row4</td>
                <td>row5</td>
                <td>row6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row7</td>
                <td>row8</td>
                <td>row9</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row10</td>
                <td>row11</td>
                <td>row12</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to use pseudo for **.c-table td** because it makes a visual diffrence. ( visible in chrome )

[image]

http://fiddle.jshell.net/UXeBj/10/

**Temporary solution**

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {

.c-table td:before {
    content: none;
}

.c-table td {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}

}
```

Comment: Are you using the most up to date version of Mozilla? Try using the unprefixed version of box shadow and please let me know what you find .

Comment: He's right, it ain't working on Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: I'm using 26.0 version

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fbox-shadow Firefox 4+ supports box-shadow, Firefox 3.5,3.6 supports -moz-box-shadow and then anything before Firefox 3.0 does not support box shadowing.

Comment: I would advise looking at this SO question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755682/css-mozilla-bug-box-shadowinset-not-working-properly

Comment: I don't know why you are using `before` and positioning as you can do it with out these. Here is a [Working Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/UXeBj/12/)

Comment: You don't see the diffrence ?

Comment: @MackoTarana were my links helpful?

Comment: Not really but i appreciate that :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Position on ::after in table-cell doesn't work in Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736050/position-on-after-in-table-cell-doesnt-work-in-firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently this bug report causes the same issue:

### https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63895